# zsh completion: compadd strings with hyphens and spaces

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

This command works:
`compadd - '-test1 text' '-test1 qwer'`

This command works too:
`compadd -Q - '-test1 text' '-test2 qwer'`

But if first words are the same, then the command does not works: 
`compadd -Q - '-test1 text' '-test1 qwer'`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, huh?

`compadd -Q - '-test1\ text' '-test1\ qwer'`